# Set Version Number in psm1 file

Tags: powershell

I have a simple PowerShell module contained in a .psm1 file. Is it possible to assign a version number to the module without creating a manifest?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - "no"

Longer answer - the version for a Powershell module is determined by the module manifest.  You can create this by running the `New-ModuleManifest` cmdlet, or by manually creating the manifest file and putting it in a fresh "psd1" file with the same name as your module.